# Reading and displaying Values from Sqlite3 Database with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I am writing a application that will read values from an SQlite3 database and display them through webbrowser with PHP. This is new to me and I have tried several things but can't seem to get it to work! The values are listed as REAL in the database, which should be PARAM_STR.

```
<?php
    $db = new SQLite3('/home/pi/ECE522/test.db');
    if(!$db) {
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {
      echo "Opened DATABASE!";
      $query = $db->prepare('SELECT df1, df2 FROM PLCValues');
      $query->bindParm('df1', $df1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParm('df2', $df2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->execute();
      var_dump($df1);
      var_dump($df2);
      echo $df1;
      echo $df2;   
   }
?>
```

On the webpage I get "Opened DATABASE!" but nothing else?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You don't define the $df1 and $df2 before executing the query, that you bind as param at

```
$query->bindParm('df1', $df1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParm('df2', $df2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Do you realy need that?
If you just want to select all values in columns 'df1' and 'df2' from PLCValues table, I think you need something like this:

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT df1, df2 FROM PLCValues");
while (($row = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))) {
  var_dump($row);
}
```

For more information see examples from http://php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3stmt.bindparam.php

If you want to select values with certain df1, I think you need something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT df1, df2 FROM PLCValues WHERE df1=:df1");
$stmt->bindParam(':df1', '[WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SELECT]', [YOUR_DATA_TYPE]);
$result = $stmt->execute();
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
```

Comment: I have 40 some variables in the table. I only need those two at this time.

Comment: Can you try to use variant from php documentation (see link in my answer)?
If you want to use params also see link from answer.
If you want to select values with certain id, I think you need something like this:

Comment: If you want to select values with certain df1, I think you need something like this:
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT df1, df2 FROM PLCValues WHERE df1=:df1");
$stmt->bindParam(':df1', '[WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SELECT], [YOUR_DATA_TYPE]);
$result = $stmt->execute();
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
See the end of answer